# I am making a http get call to get the image url status is ok or not but it's giving an error?

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient

i have an `angular` app in which i have a `div` in which i am binding a `background-image`. But sometimes it's link broken. So i decided to make an `http` get call first for each time to get whether `image url` status is ok or not.

Here is the `service.ts` code

```
get = (): Observable<any> => {
    return this._http.get(`http://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500`, { headers: this.getHeaders()})
}

private getHeaders = () => {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    return headers;
}
```

Here is my `component.ts`

```
this.__ds.get().subscribe(resp=>{
  console.log(resp)
}, error => {
      console.log('Search Category By referral Error : ', error);
    })
}
```

Problem is that each time i am getting an error like this

[image]

Here is my stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pjavzx)

Comment: your input URL is giving this error `URL signature expired`. please recheck

Comment: Yea if url is replaced with another it all works

Comment: @Hareesh but if you will copy this url to your browser so in browser image will be load

Comment: not in my browser, the url look like coming from facebook cdn. May be you are signed in facebook in your browser, and angular http client not able to access it.

Comment: @Hareesh please try to put any other url yourself and then see what's happening in stackblitz

Comment: @FahadHassan yes i tried, and its working fine with random image urls.

Comment: @Hareesh please try this url in stackblitz `https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506355683710-bd071c0a5828?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80` and you will see that logs will be print in observable's error block